# Flutter iOS Push Notification Issue in Release Mode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have added push notification into my flutter app.
Its working in android release and debug mode, also in iOS Debug Mode.
But when i change the scheme to Release in iOS, its not working.
I have added Appdelegateproxy to false, created release apns certificate, I am using Firebase messaging. Please help me on this. Its been a while i got stuck in this.

I added Capabilities also

Comment: Please add a detailed description of the steps you have tried and the exact issue that you are facing. The question is very abstract.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reponse: I have added dependency firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16, i am using flutter version v1.17.0. I have done all the necessary things to enable push notification in both ios and android. 
Added dependencies
Added json and google-info.plist
The push notifications are working perfectly in Android build.
Its also working perfectly in iOS Debug build.

Comment: if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(
          IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, provisional: false));
      _fcm.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
        print("Settings registered: $settings");
      });
    }

Comment: _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onMessage $message');
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onBackGroundMessage $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onLaunch $message');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onResume $message');
      },
    );